# Apache cxf: How to overwrite xsd in wsdl, if I use code-first approach and generate jaxb from xsd

Tags: spring, xsd, wsdl, cxf, code-first

Several days I'm struggling with this problem.
I have xsd, then I generate jaxb from it, write service and annotate them.
And get wsdl, but I want to use my initial xsd in wsdl, not apache cxf is made for me.
Yes, it's like spring-ws do things, but I want Apache cxf, because it have features like GzipInInteceptor. And I do not find how to decompress incoming request via spring-ws.

Update:
I've solved it.

    `endpoint.setSchemaLocations(new ArrayList<String>() {{
                add("classpath:/resources/ws/xsd/StatusPolicyEOSAGOStatusRequest.xsd");
                add("classpath:/resources/ws/xsd/StatusPolicyEOSAGOStatusResponse.xsd");
    }});`

Comment: Explain with sample code.